# Ubuntu 13.04 "could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"

Tags: 13.04, skype, steam, opengl, mesa

Just recently upgraded to 13.04 and am having trouble running TF2 via Steam. Whenever I start Steam I get a dialog saying:

> OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.

Every time I go to launch TF2 I get a dialog saying:

> Could not find required OpenGL entry pint 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.

I tried updating my Nvidia drivers, hoping that would solve this issue but alas, it did not. I believe this issue is related to a fix I used to get Skype working with 13.04, specifically [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/287741/155333). Just a heads up I'm using GNOME Shell 3.8.

Let me know if you need anymore information about my system.